# When to use UUID instead of millisecond timestamp in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, timestamp, datastax-java-driver

I have created table in **cassandra**, where primary key is some column with `timeuuid` as datatype. I am able to identify each record uniquely with just millisecond precision timestamp value stored as `bigint`.

I have used **java** datastax driver to connect cassandra. Before inserting record into database I am converting millisecond timestamp into UUID for each record. Which is overhead and can be removed.

1. Can some one explain what are the benefits of using `timeuuid` instead of `bigint` considering records are able to identified without timeuuid's uniqueness ?
2. Is there any performance impact in between `timeuuid` and `bigint` data type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be very big impact for performance if you generate timeuuid from timestamp. `timeuuid` is useful if you may have many events happening in the same millisecond, and you need sorting - with `timeuuid` you may get up to 10,000 different values inside the millisecond. Typical use case is the table with structure like this:

```
create table tuuid (
  pk int,
  tuuid timeuuid, 
  ....
  ....,
  primary key (pk, tuiid));
```

In this case, you will get sorting (ascending or descending) together with uniqueness of values for `tuuid`. Of course you can come with primary key of `(pk, timestamp, random-value)`, but with `timeuuid` you don't need to have an additional column for uniqueness.  One of the drawback of `timeuuid` is integration with Spark, for example, as it doesn't have this type, and may not able to perform pushing of the filters.

If you don't need uniqueness, then just switch to `timestamp` - it's represented as 8-bytes long internally - the same as `bigint`, but you don't need to do conversions yourself, etc.